# Difference between Dir.glob and Find

Tags: ruby

What is the difference between:

```
Dir.glob(File.join('.', '**', '*')).each do |e|

end
```

and

```
require 'find'
Find.find('.').each do |e|

end
```

Despite the fact that Find is 3 times slower.

Answer (score 1):

`Dir.glob` iterates over all files/directories that match the argument possibly including wild characters in a flat way, whereas `Find.find` first iterates over a direct files/directories that match the exact path name, then looks into its direct files/directories in a recursive way. With `Find.find`, you can skip the whole directory.

Comment: Thanks! What you mean is that glob is doing a depth first traversal while Find is doing a breadth first traversal? Right?

Comment: No. glob dispenses with the notion of depth. I haven't made it clear, but find actually does depth first.